# AFHTTPSessionManager returns -999 error when I try to connect to https

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

The code below works fine for one server, but returns -999 error when I change connection URL on the copy of server.
Both of servers https. sessionManager is the variable of class with strong link.
Maybe someone solved this problem before.

```
AFOAuthCredential *credential=[AFOAuthCredential retrieveCredentialWithIdentifier:kAuthorizationCredentials];
sessionManager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:kAuthorizationUrl];
[sessionManager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithCredential: credential];

[sessionManager GET:@"devices/serialnumbers/powermotes"
    parameters:nil
    progress:nil
    success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        successfulCallback(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
               }
];
```

Comment: The server does not return anything. -999 means that the connection got cancelled. Check the detail of the error object in your failure block.

Comment: Try log: NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; and NSLog(@"error %@", error); What does the response say?